# iOS: UIImageViews added to UIScrollView before ASIHTTP finishes fetching image data

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, asihttprequest

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm trying to create a scroll view that shows images in a grid.
I use `ASIHTTPRequest` to fetch images from a web service I created. In `-viewDidLoad` I call a method to fetch the images and then add image views to the scroll view.

The thing I'm struggling with is that my image views are added to the scroll view before the `ASIHTTPRequest` finishes fetching. As a result, my scroll view is empty. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Reload the tableview when ASIHTTP finishes fetching

Comment: @AmitVyawahare: The original poster describes a scroll view with manually added image view subviews, not a table view.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as "accepted." Otherwise, i'm happy to clarify it if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to maintain references to your image views, setting their images using the data from the completed request. As you add the image views, enter them into an array. Next, assign your requests an index using a key in the `userInfo` dictionary on `ASIHTTPRequest`. Then, when the request completes, instantiate an image with the response data, read out the request index, and assign the image to the image view at this index in your array.

Of course, this is just one approach. As your grid grows larger, you will run into memory and performance constraints. At that point, you can choose to adapt a `UITableView`, adopt a third-party grid implementation, or implement view reuse yourself.